# How can I achieve the return type always to be optional from a generic function (Typescript)

Tags: typescript, generics, next.js

How can I achieve the return type always to be optional from a generic return type in functions?

Basically, I want the return types (data & error) to be optional always as one of them will be undefined always.

Ts -> declarations

```
import getConfig from 'next/config';
import axios, { AxiosRequestConfig } from 'axios';

import { MethodCall } from './methods';

const { publicRuntimeConfig } = getConfig();


export interface HttpReturnSuccess<TData = unknown> {
    data: TData;
    error: undefined;
    isError: false;
}

export interface HttpReturnError<TError = unknown>
     {
    data: undefined;
    error: TError;
    isError: true;
}

export type HttpReturn<TData = unknown, TError = unknown> =
    | HttpReturnSuccess<TData>
    | HttpReturnError<TError>;

export interface HttpProps<TPayload> {
    method: MethodCall;
    path: string;
    data?: TPayload;
    config?: AxiosRequestConfig;
}
```

Here is the function. What I want is when it returns the object `{data: Data, error: Error}` it should give me optional data & error. For example
-> `{data?: Data, error?: Error}`

```
const baseUrl = publicRuntimeConfig.baseUrl;

export const internalHttp = async <Data = unknown, Payload = unknown, Error = unknown>(
    props: HttpProps<Payload>
): Promise<HttpReturn<Data, Error>> => {
    const { method, path, data: body, config } = props;

    const returnedValue = {
        data: undefined,
        error: undefined,
        isError: false,
    };

    const url = baseUrl + ':' + path;

    const options = [body, config];

    if (method === MethodCall.Get) options.shift();

    try {
        const { data } = await axios[method]<Data>(url, ...options);

        returnedValue.data = data as Data;
    } catch (error) {
        returnedValue.error = error as Error;

        returnedValue.isError = true;
    }

    return returnedValue;
};

const {data} = internalHttp<{name: "amed"}>() 

// I want data to be Data | undefined. 

// TS suggestions -> data.name | I want -> data?.name -> this behaviour
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/wjJEMw) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: Hi, Sorry about that I modified my question to the most understandable way from my side. Please feel free to check the code above.

Comment: Hmm, when I drop that into the TypeScript Playground [there are still a bunch of errors seemingly unrelated to your issue](https://tsplay.dev/Wv8JnN).  If people can't easily reproduce your problem, they might not be able or willing to spend the time it takes to do so before they answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to supply the return type inline with the function definition:

```
export const internalHttp = async <
    Data = unknown,
    Payload = unknown,
    Error = unknown
>(
    props: HttpProps<Data ,Error>
) : {data: Data | undefined, error: Error | undefined, isError: boolean} => { ... }
```

Comment: Hi, @Zze I have tried it. But the same problem, when I call the func it gives me ```data``` back without ```Data | undefined```